# Calculate percent of sum on row level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rows, percentage, date-arithmetic

I have query:

`select my_year,my_month, L2, PAR1, PAR2, PAR3, Value from table1`

to produce below table:
[image]

Now I want to calculate percent for each row. First I need to add values (20+30+40+50+60+70+80) and then divide each row by the sum.
Result should be:
[image]

Can I do it in one select? or should I calculate sum in second query and then make join?

Comment: You can do it in one select with a sub-select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percentage of each row in SQL Server 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969675/how-to-calculate-percentage-of-each-row-in-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions.  For the data you present:

```
select my_year, my_month, L2, PAR1, PAR2, PAR3, Value,
       Value * 100.0 / SUM(Value) OVER () as percent
from table1;
```

Comment: thank you! for my puprose I just did: Value/sum(Value) Over()

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a single query, like so:

```
select
    my_year,
    my_month,
    L2,
    PAR1,
    PAR2,
    PAR3,
    Value,
    (100.0 * Value) / SUM(Value) OVER ()
from
    table1
```

Comment: @TabAlleman yes you're right. I've updated my answer. Thanks!